# Why there are edges and wrong figure displayed after exporting a Polygon

Tags: graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format, polygons

**Bug introduced in 12.3.1 or earlier and persisting in 13.1.0** [CASE:4897465]

---

I use `Polygon` to plot a figure, and then export it to different formats. The SVG and PDF formats display a wrong figure.

I expected to get a polygon without edges when exporting to PDF format.

[image]

```
data={{0.999916,0.0129555},{0.999367,0.012945},{0.998819,0.0129279},{0.998271,0.012904},{0.997723,0.0128735},{0.997176,0.0128363},{0.996629,0.0127924},{0.996082,0.0127418},{0.995537,0.0126846},{0.994992,0.0126207},{0.994447,0.0125501},{0.993904,0.0124729},{0.993362,0.0123891},{0.992821,0.0122987},{0.992281,0.0122017},{0.991742,0.0120981},{0.991204,0.0119879},{0.990668,0.0118712},{0.990134,0.0117479},{0.9896,0.0116182},{0.989069,0.0114819},{0.988539,0.0113391},{0.988011,0.0111899},{0.987485,0.0110343},{0.986961,0.0108722},{0.986439,0.0107038},{0.985918,0.010529},{0.985401,0.0103478},{0.984885,0.0101604},{0.984371,0.00996664},{0.983861,0.00976666},{0.983352,0.00956045},{0.982846,0.00934806},{0.982343,0.0091295},{0.981842,0.00890482},{0.981344,0.00867404},{0.980849,0.0084372},{0.980357,0.00819434},{0.979868,0.00794549},{0.979382,0.00769069},{0.9789,0.00742998},{0.97842,0.00716339},{0.977944,0.00689097},{0.977471,0.00661276},{0.977001,0.00632879},{0.976535,0.00603912},{0.976073,0.00574377},{0.975614,0.00544281},{0.975159,0.00513626},{0.974708,0.00482419},{0.97426,0.00450663},{0.973817,0.00418362},{0.973377,0.00385523},{0.972942,0.0035215},{0.97251,0.00318248},{0.972083,0.00283822},{0.97166,0.00248876},{0.971241,0.00213417},{0.970827,0.00177449},{0.970417,0.00140978},{0.970011,0.0010401},{0.969611,0.000665493},{0.969214,0.00028602},{0.968823,-0.0000982618},{0.968436,-0.000487296},{0.968053,-0.000881025},{0.967676,-0.00127939},{0.967304,-0.00168233},{0.966936,-0.00208979},{0.966574,-0.0025017},{0.966216,-0.002918},{0.965864,-0.00333864},{0.965517,-0.00376355},{0.965175,-0.00419266},{0.964838,-0.00462592},{0.964507,-0.00506325},{0.964181,-0.0055046},{0.96386,-0.00594989},{0.963545,-0.00639906},{0.963235,-0.00685205},{0.962931,-0.00730878},{0.962633,-0.00776919},{0.96234,-0.00823321},{0.962053,-0.00870077},{0.961771,-0.0091718},{0.961496,-0.00964623},{0.961226,-0.010124},{0.960962,-0.010605},{0.960704,-0.0110892},{0.960452,-0.0115765},{0.960205,-0.0120669},{0.959965,-0.0125602},{0.959731,-0.0130564},{0.959503,-0.0135555},{0.959281,-0.0140573},{0.959065,-0.0145617},{0.958856,-0.0150688},{0.958652,-0.0155784},{0.958455,-0.0160904},{0.958264,-0.0166048},{0.958079,-0.0171215},{0.957901,-0.0176404},{0.957729,-0.0181614},{0.957563,-0.0186846},{0.957404,-0.0192096},{0.957251,-0.0197366},{0.957105,-0.0202654},{0.956965,-0.020796},{0.956832,-0.0213282},{0.956705,-0.0218621},{0.956584,-0.0223974},{0.956471,-0.0229342},{0.956363,-0.0234723},{0.956263,-0.0240116},{0.956169,-0.0245522},{0.956081,-0.0250939},{0.956,-0.0256366},{0.955926,-0.0261802},{0.955858,-0.0267248},{0.955797,-0.0272701},{0.955743,-0.0278161},{0.955695,-0.0283627},{0.955655,-0.0289099},{0.95562,-0.0294575},{0.955593,-0.0300055},{0.955572,-0.0305538},{0.955558,-0.0311023},{0.95555,-0.0316509},{0.955549,-0.0321996},{0.955555,-0.0327483},{0.955568,-0.0332969},{0.955587,-0.0338452},{0.955613,-0.0343933},{0.955646,-0.034941},{0.955685,-0.0354883},{0.955731,-0.0360351},{0.955784,-0.0365812},{0.955843,-0.0371267},{0.955909,-0.0376714},{0.955982,-0.0382153},{0.956061,-0.0387582},{0.956147,-0.0393001},{0.95624,-0.039841},{0.956339,-0.0403806},{0.956445,-0.0409191},{0.956557,-0.0414561},{0.956676,-0.0419918},{0.956801,-0.042526},{0.956933,-0.0430586},{0.957071,-0.0435896},{0.957216,-0.0441188},{0.957367,-0.0446463},{0.957525,-0.0451718},{0.957689,-0.0456954},{0.95786,-0.0462169},{0.958036,-0.0467363},{0.95822,-0.0472536},{0.958409,-0.0477685},{0.958605,-0.0482811},{0.958807,-0.0487913},{0.959015,-0.0492989},{0.959229,-0.049804},{0.95945,-0.0503065},{0.959677,-0.0508062},{0.959909,-0.0513031},{0.960148,-0.0517971},{0.960393,-0.0522882},{0.960644,-0.0527762},{0.9609,-0.0532612},{0.961163,-0.0537429},{0.961431,-0.0542215},{0.961706,-0.0546967},{0.961986,-0.0551685},{0.962271,-0.0556369},{0.962563,-0.0561018},{0.96286,-0.0565631},{0.963163,-0.0570207},{0.963471,-0.0574745},{0.963785,-0.0579246},{0.964104,-0.0583708},{0.964429,-0.0588131},{0.964759,-0.0592514},{0.965095,-0.0596856},{0.965435,-0.0601157},{0.965781,-0.0605417},{0.966132,-0.0609633},{0.966489,-0.0613806},{0.96685,-0.0617936},{0.967216,-0.0622021},{0.967587,-0.0626061},{0.967964,-0.0630056},{0.968345,-0.0634004},{0.96873,-0.0637906},{0.969121,-0.064176},{0.969516,-0.0645566},{0.969916,-0.0649324},{0.97032,-0.0653032},{0.970729,-0.0656691},{0.971143,-0.06603},{0.97156,-0.0663858},{0.971982,-0.0667365},{0.972409,-0.067082},{0.972839,-0.0674222},{0.973274,-0.0677572},{0.973712,-0.0680869},{0.974155,-0.0684112},{0.974601,-0.06873},{0.975052,-0.0690434},{0.975506,-0.0693513},{0.975964,-0.0696536},{0.976426,-0.0699502},{0.976891,-0.0702413},{0.977359,-0.0705266},{0.977831,-0.0708062},{0.978307,-0.07108},{0.978786,-0.0713479},{0.979268,-0.07161},{0.979753,-0.0718662},{0.980241,-0.0721165},{0.980733,-0.0723608},{0.981227,-0.0725991},{0.981724,-0.0728313},{0.982224,-0.0730574},{0.982727,-0.0732774},{0.983232,-0.0734913},{0.98374,-0.0736989},{0.98425,-0.0739004},{0.984763,-0.0740956},{0.985278,-0.0742846},{0.985796,-0.0744672},{0.986315,-0.0746435},{0.986837,-0.0748135},{0.987361,-0.074977},{0.987886,-0.0751342},{0.988414,-0.0752849},{0.988943,-0.0754292},{0.989474,-0.075567},{0.990007,-0.0756984},{0.990541,-0.0758232},{0.991077,-0.0759414},{0.991614,-0.0760532},{0.992153,-0.0761583},{0.992693,-0.0762569},{0.993234,-0.0763489},{0.993776,-0.0764343},{0.994319,-0.076513},{0.994863,-0.0765851},{0.995407,-0.0766506},{0.995953,-0.0767094},{0.996499,-0.0767616},{0.997046,-0.0768071},{0.999916,0.0129296},{0.999917,0.0128778},{0.999918,0.0128259},{0.999918,0.0127741},{0.999919,0.0127223},{0.99992,0.0126705},{0.99992,0.0126187},{0.999921,0.0125668},{0.999922,0.012515},{0.999922,0.0124632},{0.999923,0.0124114},{0.999924,0.0123596},{0.999924,0.0123078},{0.999925,0.0122559},{0.999926,0.0122041},{0.999926,0.0121523},{0.999927,0.0121005},{0.999927,0.0120487},{0.999928,0.0119968},{0.999929,0.011945},{0.999929,0.0118932},{0.99993,0.0118414},{0.999931,0.0117896},{0.999931,0.0117377},{0.999932,0.0116859},{0.999932,0.0116341},{0.999933,0.0115823},{0.999934,0.0115305},{0.999934,0.0114786},{0.999935,0.0114268},{0.999935,0.011375},{0.999936,0.0113232},{0.999936,0.0112714},{0.999937,0.0112195},{0.999938,0.0111677},{0.999938,0.0111159},{0.999939,0.0110641},{0.999939,0.0110123},{0.99994,0.0109604},{0.99994,0.0109086},{0.999941,0.0108568},{0.999942,0.010805},{0.999942,0.0107532},{0.999943,0.0107013},{0.999943,0.0106495},{0.999944,0.0105977},{0.999944,0.0105459},{0.999945,0.0104941},{0.999945,0.0104422},{0.999946,0.0103904},{0.999947,0.0103386},{0.999947,0.0102868},{0.999948,0.0102349},{0.999948,0.0101831},{0.999949,0.0101313},{0.999949,0.0100795},{0.99995,0.0100277},{0.99995,0.00997584},{0.999951,0.00992402},{0.999951,0.0098722},{0.999952,0.00982038},{0.999952,0.00976856},{0.999953,0.00971674},{0.999953,0.00966492},{0.999954,0.0096131},{0.999954,0.00956128},{0.999955,0.00950946},{0.999955,0.00945763},{0.999956,0.00940581},{0.999956,0.00935399},{0.999957,0.00930217},{0.999957,0.00925035},{0.999958,0.00919853},{0.999958,0.00914671},{0.999959,0.00909489},{0.999959,0.00904306},{0.99996,0.00899124},{0.99996,0.00893942},{0.999961,0.0088876},{0.999961,0.00883578},{0.999961,0.00878396},{0.999962,0.00873214},{0.999962,0.00868031},{0.999963,0.00862849},{0.999963,0.00857667},{0.999964,0.00852485},{0.999964,0.00847303},{0.999965,0.00842121},{0.999965,0.00836939},{0.999965,0.00831756},{0.999966,0.00826574},{0.999966,0.00821392},{0.999967,0.0081621},{0.999967,0.00811028},{0.999968,0.00805846},{0.999968,0.00800663},{0.999968,0.00795481},{0.999969,0.00790299},{0.999969,0.00785117},{0.99997,0.00779935},{0.99997,0.00774752},{0.99997,0.0076957},{0.999971,0.00764388},{0.999971,0.00759206},{0.999972,0.00754024},{0.999972,0.00748841},{0.999972,0.00743659},{0.999973,0.00738477},{0.999973,0.00733295},{0.999973,0.00728113},{0.999974,0.0072293},{0.999974,0.00717748},{0.999975,0.00712566},{0.999975,0.00707384},{0.999975,0.00702202},{0.999976,0.00697019},{0.999976,0.00691837},{0.999976,0.00686655},{0.999977,0.00681473},{0.999977,0.00676291},{0.999977,0.00671108},{0.999978,0.00665926},{0.999978,0.00660744},{0.999979,0.00655562},{0.999979,0.00650379},{0.999979,0.00645197},{0.99998,0.00640015},{0.99998,0.00634833},{0.99998,0.0062965},{0.999981,0.00624468},{0.999981,0.00619286},{0.999981,0.00614104},{0.999981,0.00608921},{0.999982,0.00603739},{0.999982,0.00598557},{0.999982,0.00593375},{0.999983,0.00588192},{0.999983,0.0058301},{0.999983,0.00577828},{0.999984,0.00572646},{0.999984,0.00567463},{0.999984,0.00562281},{0.999984,0.00557099},{0.999985,0.00551917},{0.999985,0.00546734},{0.999985,0.00541552},{0.999986,0.0053637},{0.999986,0.00531188},{0.999986,0.00526005},{0.999986,0.00520823},{0.999987,0.00515641},{0.999987,0.00510459},{0.999987,0.00505276},{0.999987,0.00500094},{0.999988,0.00494912},{0.999988,0.00489729},{0.999988,0.00484547},{0.999989,0.00479365},{0.999989,0.00474183},{0.999989,0.00469},{0.999989,0.00463818},{0.999989,0.00458636},{0.99999,0.00453453},{0.99999,0.00448271},{0.99999,0.00443089},{0.99999,0.00437907},{0.999991,0.00432724},{0.999991,0.00427542},{0.999991,0.0042236},{0.999991,0.00417177},{0.999992,0.00411995},{0.999992,0.00406813},{0.999992,0.0040163},{0.999992,0.00396448},{0.999992,0.00391266},{0.999993,0.00386084},{0.999993,0.00380901},{0.999993,0.00375719},{0.999993,0.00370537},{0.999993,0.00365354},{0.999994,0.00360172},{0.999994,0.0035499},{0.999994,0.00349807},{0.999994,0.00344625},{0.999994,0.00339443},{0.999994,0.0033426},{0.999995,0.00329078},{0.999995,0.00323896},{0.999995,0.00318714},{0.999995,0.00313531},{0.999995,0.00308349},{0.999995,0.00303167},{0.999996,0.00297984},{0.999996,0.00292802},{0.999996,0.0028762},{0.999996,0.00282437},{0.999996,0.00277255},{0.999996,0.00272073},{0.999996,0.0026689},{0.999997,0.00261708},{0.999997,0.00256526},{0.999997,0.00251343},{0.999997,0.00246161},{0.999997,0.00240979},{0.999997,0.00235796},{0.999997,0.00230614},{0.999997,0.00225432},{0.999998,0.00220249},{0.999998,0.00215067},{0.999998,0.00209885},{0.999998,0.00204702},{0.999998,0.0019952},{0.999998,0.00194338},{0.999998,0.00189155},{0.999998,0.00183973},{0.999998,0.00178791},{0.999998,0.00173608},{0.999999,0.00168426},{0.999999,0.00163244},{0.999999,0.00158061},{0.999999,0.00152879},{0.999999,0.00147697},{0.999999,0.00142514},{0.999999,0.00137332},{0.999999,0.0013215},{0.999999,0.00126967},{0.999999,0.00121785},{0.999999,0.00116603},{0.999999,0.0011142},{0.999999,0.00106238},{0.999999,0.00101056},{1.,0.000958733},{1.,0.00090691},{1.,0.000855086},{1.,0.000803263},{1.,0.00075144},{1.,0.000699616},{1.,0.000647793},{1.,0.000595969},{1.,0.000544146},{1.,0.000492323},{1.,0.000440499},{1.,0.000388676},{1.,0.000336852},{1.,0.000285029},{1.,0.000233205},{1.,0.000181382},{1.,0.000129559},{1.,0.0000777351},{1.,0.0000259117},{1.,0.},{0.999606,-2.42286*10^-6},{0.999213,-9.69109*10^-6},{0.998819,-0.0000218036},{0.998426,-0.0000387585},{0.998033,-0.0000605533},{0.99764,-0.0000871846},{0.997248,-0.000118648},{0.996856,-0.00015494},{0.996465,-0.000196054},{0.996074,-0.000241984},{0.995683,-0.000292723},{0.995294,-0.000348263},{0.994905,-0.000408596},{0.994516,-0.000473713},{0.994129,-0.000543604},{0.993743,-0.000618258},{0.993357,-0.000697665},{0.992973,-0.000781811},{0.992589,-0.000870685},{0.992207,-0.000964272},{0.991826,-0.00106256},{0.991446,-0.00116553},{0.991067,-0.00127317},{0.99069,-0.00138546},{0.990314,-0.00150239},{0.98994,-0.00162394},{0.989567,-0.00175009},{0.989195,-0.00188082},{0.988826,-0.0020161},{0.988458,-0.00215593},{0.988092,-0.00230028},{0.987727,-0.00244912},{0.987365,-0.00260244},{0.987004,-0.00276021},{0.986645,-0.00292241},{0.986289,-0.00308901},{0.985934,-0.00325999},{0.985582,-0.00343532},{0.985232,-0.00361497},{0.984884,-0.00379893},{0.984538,-0.00398715},{0.984195,-0.00417961},{0.983854,-0.00437629},{0.983515,-0.00457715},{0.983179,-0.00478216},{0.982846,-0.00499129},{0.982515,-0.00520452},{0.982186,-0.00542179},{0.981861,-0.0056431},{0.981538,-0.00586839},{0.981218,-0.00609764},{0.980901,-0.00633081},{0.980587,-0.00656787},{0.980276,-0.00680877},{0.979967,-0.0070535},{0.979662,-0.00730199},{0.97936,-0.00755423},{0.979061,-0.00781017},{0.978765,-0.00806977},{0.978472,-0.00833299},{0.978183,-0.0085998},{0.977897,-0.00887015},{0.977614,-0.009144},{0.977335,-0.00942131},{0.977059,-0.00970204},{0.976786,-0.00998614},{0.976517,-0.0102736},{0.976252,-0.0105643},{0.97599,-0.0108583},{0.975732,-0.0111554},{0.975478,-0.0114558},{0.975227,-0.0117592},{0.97498,-0.0120657},{0.974737,-0.0123752},{0.974497,-0.0126877},{0.974262,-0.0130031},{0.97403,-0.0133214},{0.973803,-0.0136425},{0.973579,-0.0139664},{0.973359,-0.014293},{0.973144,-0.0146223},{0.972932,-0.0149542},{0.972725,-0.0152887},{0.972521,-0.0156258},{0.972322,-0.0159653},{0.972127,-0.0163072},{0.971936,-0.0166515},{0.97175,-0.0169982},{0.971568,-0.0173471},{0.97139,-0.0176982},{0.971216,-0.0180515},{0.971047,-0.0184069},{0.970882,-0.0187643},{0.970722,-0.0191238},{0.970566,-0.0194852},{0.970414,-0.0198485},{0.970267,-0.0202136},{0.970125,-0.0205805},{0.969987,-0.0209491},{0.969853,-0.0213195},{0.969724,-0.0216914},{0.9696,-0.0220649},{0.96948,-0.0224399},{0.969365,-0.0228163},{0.969255,-0.0231941},{0.969149,-0.0235732},{0.969048,-0.0239537},{0.968952,-0.0243353},{0.96886,-0.0247181},{0.968773,-0.025102},{0.968691,-0.0254869},{0.968613,-0.0258729},{0.96854,-0.0262597},{0.968473,-0.0266474},{0.968409,-0.0270359},{0.968351,-0.0274252},{0.968297,-0.0278152},{0.968249,-0.0282057},{0.968205,-0.0285969},{0.968165,-0.0289886},{0.968131,-0.0293807},{0.968102,-0.0297732},{0.968077,-0.0301661},{0.968057,-0.0305592},{0.968042,-0.0309525},{0.968032,-0.031346},{0.968027,-0.0317396},{0.968026,-0.0321332},{0.96803,-0.0325268},{0.96804,-0.0329203},{0.968054,-0.0333137},{0.968073,-0.0337069},{0.968096,-0.0340998},{0.968125,-0.0344924},{0.968158,-0.0348846},{0.968197,-0.0352763},{0.96824,-0.0356676},{0.968288,-0.0360583},{0.96834,-0.0364484},{0.968398,-0.0368378},{0.96846,-0.0372264},{0.968527,-0.0376143},{0.968599,-0.0380013},{0.968675,-0.0383874},{0.968757,-0.0387726},{0.968843,-0.0391567},{0.968934,-0.0395397},{0.969029,-0.0399215},{0.969129,-0.0403022},{0.969234,-0.0406816},{0.969344,-0.0410597},{0.969458,-0.0414364},{0.969577,-0.0418117},{0.9697,-0.0421854},{0.969828,-0.0425577},{0.969961,-0.0429283},{0.970098,-0.0432973},{0.970239,-0.0436645},{0.970385,-0.04403},{0.970536,-0.0443936},{0.970691,-0.0447554},{0.970851,-0.0451152},{0.971015,-0.0454731},{0.971183,-0.0458289},{0.971356,-0.0461826},{0.971533,-0.0465341},{0.971714,-0.0468834},{0.9719,-0.0472305},{0.97209,-0.0475753},{0.972284,-0.0479177},{0.972483,-0.0482577},{0.972685,-0.0485952},{0.972892,-0.0489302},{0.973103,-0.0492626},{0.973317,-0.0495924},{0.973536,-0.0499196},{0.973759,-0.050244},{0.973986,-0.0505656},{0.974217,-0.0508845},{0.974452,-0.0512004},{0.97469,-0.0515135},{0.974933,-0.0518236},{0.975179,-0.0521306},{0.975429,-0.0524347},{0.975683,-0.0527356},{0.97594,-0.0530334},{0.976201,-0.053328},{0.976466,-0.0536193},{0.976734,-0.0539074},{0.977006,-0.0541921},{0.977281,-0.0544735},{0.97756,-0.0547515},{0.977842,-0.055026},{0.978127,-0.0552971},{0.978416,-0.0555645},{0.978708,-0.0558285},{0.979003,-0.0560888},{0.979302,-0.0563454},{0.979604,-0.0565984},{0.979908,-0.0568476},{0.980216,-0.057093},{0.980527,-0.0573347},{0.98084,-0.0575725},{0.981157,-0.0578064},{0.981476,-0.0580364},{0.981799,-0.0582625},{0.982124,-0.0584846},{0.982451,-0.0587026},{0.982782,-0.0589166},{0.983115,-0.0591265},{0.98345,-0.0593323},{0.983788,-0.059534},{0.984129,-0.0597315},{0.984472,-0.0599248},{0.984817,-0.0601138},{0.985164,-0.0602986},{0.985514,-0.0604791},{0.985866,-0.0606552},{0.98622,-0.0608271},{0.986577,-0.0609945},{0.986935,-0.0611576},{0.987295,-0.0613162},{0.987657,-0.0614704},{0.988021,-0.0616201},{0.988387,-0.0617653},{0.988755,-0.061906},{0.989124,-0.0620422},{0.989495,-0.0621738},{0.989868,-0.0623008},{0.990242,-0.0624232},{0.990617,-0.0625411},{0.990994,-0.0626542},{0.991373,-0.0627628},{0.991752,-0.0628667},{0.992133,-0.0629658},{0.992515,-0.0630603},{0.992899,-0.0631501},{0.993283,-0.0632352},{0.993668,-0.0633155},{0.994055,-0.0633911},{0.994442,-0.0634619},{0.99483,-0.0635279},{0.995219,-0.0635892},{0.995608,-0.0636456},{0.995998,-0.0636973},{0.996389,-0.0637442},{0.996781,-0.0637862},{0.997172,-0.0638234},{0.997565,-0.0638558},{0.997957,-0.0638834},{0.997956,-0.0639092},{0.997952,-0.063961},{0.997949,-0.0640127},{0.997946,-0.0640644},{0.997942,-0.0641161},{0.997939,-0.0641678},{0.997936,-0.0642195},{0.997932,-0.0642713},{0.997929,-0.064323},{0.997926,-0.0643747},{0.997922,-0.0644264},{0.997919,-0.0644781},{0.997916,-0.0645298},{0.997912,-0.0645816},{0.997909,-0.0646333},{0.997906,-0.064685},{0.997902,-0.0647367},{0.997899,-0.0647884},{0.997896,-0.0648401},{0.997892,-0.0648918},{0.997889,-0.0649436},{0.997886,-0.0649953},{0.997882,-0.065047},{0.997879,-0.0650987},{0.997875,-0.0651504},{0.997872,-0.0652021},{0.997869,-0.0652538},{0.997865,-0.0653056},{0.997862,-0.0653573},{0.997859,-0.065409},{0.997855,-0.0654607},{0.997852,-0.0655124},{0.997848,-0.0655641},{0.997845,-0.0656158},{0.997842,-0.0656675},{0.997838,-0.0657193},{0.997835,-0.065771},{0.997831,-0.0658227},{0.997828,-0.0658744},{0.997825,-0.0659261},{0.997821,-0.0659778},{0.997818,-0.0660295},{0.997814,-0.0660812},{0.997811,-0.0661329},{0.997807,-0.0661846},{0.997804,-0.0662364},{0.997801,-0.0662881},{0.997797,-0.0663398},{0.997794,-0.0663915},{0.99779,-0.0664432},{0.997787,-0.0664949},{0.997783,-0.0665466},{0.99778,-0.0665983},{0.997776,-0.06665},{0.997773,-0.0667017},{0.99777,-0.0667534},{0.997766,-0.0668052},{0.997763,-0.0668569},{0.997759,-0.0669086},{0.997756,-0.0669603},{0.997752,-0.067012},{0.997749,-0.0670637},{0.997745,-0.0671154},{0.997742,-0.0671671},{0.997738,-0.0672188},{0.997735,-0.0672705},{0.997731,-0.0673222},{0.997728,-0.0673739},{0.997724,-0.0674256},{0.997721,-0.0674773},{0.997717,-0.067529},{0.997714,-0.0675807},{0.99771,-0.0676325},{0.997707,-0.0676842},{0.997703,-0.0677359},{0.9977,-0.0677876},{0.997696,-0.0678393},{0.997693,-0.067891},{0.997689,-0.0679427},{0.997686,-0.0679944},{0.997682,-0.0680461},{0.997679,-0.0680978},{0.997675,-0.0681495},{0.997672,-0.0682012},{0.997668,-0.0682529},{0.997665,-0.0683046},{0.997661,-0.0683563},{0.997657,-0.068408},{0.997654,-0.0684597},{0.99765,-0.0685114},{0.997647,-0.0685631},{0.997643,-0.0686148},{0.99764,-0.0686665},{0.997636,-0.0687182},{0.997633,-0.0687699},{0.997629,-0.0688216},{0.997625,-0.0688733},{0.997622,-0.068925},{0.997618,-0.0689767},{0.997615,-0.0690284},{0.997611,-0.0690801},{0.997608,-0.0691318},{0.997604,-0.0691835},{0.9976,-0.0692352},{0.997597,-0.0692869},{0.997593,-0.0693386},{0.99759,-0.0693903},{0.997586,-0.069442},{0.997582,-0.0694937},{0.997579,-0.0695454},{0.997575,-0.0695971},{0.997572,-0.0696488},{0.997568,-0.0697005},{0.997564,-0.0697522},{0.997561,-0.0698039},{0.997557,-0.0698556},{0.997553,-0.0699073},{0.99755,-0.069959},{0.997546,-0.0700107},{0.997543,-0.0700624},{0.997539,-0.0701141},{0.997535,-0.0701658},{0.997532,-0.0702175},{0.997528,-0.0702692},{0.997524,-0.0703209},{0.997521,-0.0703725},{0.997517,-0.0704242},{0.997513,-0.0704759},{0.99751,-0.0705276},{0.997506,-0.0705793},{0.997503,-0.070631},{0.997499,-0.0706827},{0.997495,-0.0707344},{0.997492,-0.0707861},{0.997488,-0.0708378},{0.997484,-0.0708895},{0.997481,-0.0709412},{0.997477,-0.0709929},{0.997473,-0.0710446},{0.997469,-0.0710963},{0.997466,-0.0711479},{0.997462,-0.0711996},{0.997458,-0.0712513},{0.997455,-0.071303},{0.997451,-0.0713547},{0.997447,-0.0714064},{0.997444,-0.0714581},{0.99744,-0.0715098},{0.997436,-0.0715615},{0.997432,-0.0716132},{0.997429,-0.0716649},{0.997425,-0.0717166},{0.997421,-0.0717682},{0.997418,-0.0718199},{0.997414,-0.0718716},{0.99741,-0.0719233},{0.997406,-0.071975},{0.997403,-0.0720267},{0.997399,-0.0720784},{0.997395,-0.0721301},{0.997391,-0.0721818},{0.997388,-0.0722334},{0.997384,-0.0722851},{0.99738,-0.0723368},{0.997377,-0.0723885},{0.997373,-0.0724402},{0.997369,-0.0724919},{0.997365,-0.0725436},{0.997361,-0.0725953},{0.997358,-0.0726469},{0.997354,-0.0726986},{0.99735,-0.0727503},{0.997346,-0.072802},{0.997343,-0.0728537},{0.997339,-0.0729054},{0.997335,-0.0729571},{0.997331,-0.0730087},{0.997328,-0.0730604},{0.997324,-0.0731121},{0.99732,-0.0731638},{0.997316,-0.0732155},{0.997312,-0.0732672},{0.997309,-0.0733188},{0.997305,-0.0733705},{0.997301,-0.0734222},{0.997297,-0.0734739},{0.997293,-0.0735256},{0.99729,-0.0735773},{0.997286,-0.0736289},{0.997282,-0.0736806},{0.997278,-0.0737323},{0.997274,-0.073784},{0.99727,-0.0738357},{0.997267,-0.0738874},{0.997263,-0.073939},{0.997259,-0.0739907},{0.997255,-0.0740424},{0.997251,-0.0740941},{0.997247,-0.0741458},{0.997244,-0.0741974},{0.99724,-0.0742491},{0.997236,-0.0743008},{0.997232,-0.0743525},{0.997228,-0.0744042},{0.997224,-0.0744558},{0.99722,-0.0745075},{0.997217,-0.0745592},{0.997213,-0.0746109},{0.997209,-0.0746626},{0.997205,-0.0747142},{0.997201,-0.0747659},{0.997197,-0.0748176},{0.997193,-0.0748693},{0.997189,-0.074921},{0.997186,-0.0749726},{0.997182,-0.0750243},{0.997178,-0.075076},{0.997174,-0.0751277},{0.99717,-0.0751793},{0.997166,-0.075231},{0.997162,-0.0752827},{0.997158,-0.0753344},{0.997154,-0.075386},{0.997151,-0.0754377},{0.997147,-0.0754894},{0.997143,-0.0755411},{0.997139,-0.0755927},{0.997135,-0.0756444},{0.997131,-0.0756961},{0.997127,-0.0757478},{0.997123,-0.0757994},{0.997119,-0.0758511},{0.997115,-0.0759028},{0.997111,-0.0759545},{0.997107,-0.0760061},{0.997103,-0.0760578},{0.997099,-0.0761095},{0.997096,-0.0761612},{0.997092,-0.0762128},{0.997088,-0.0762645},{0.997084,-0.0763162},{0.99708,-0.0763679},{0.997076,-0.0764195},{0.997072,-0.0764712},{0.997068,-0.0765229},{0.997064,-0.0765745},{0.99706,-0.0766262},{0.997056,-0.0766779},{0.997052,-0.0767296},{0.997048,-0.0767812}};
Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Polygon[data]}]
```

Comment: I use 13.0.0 and Win10, it not work.

Comment: `CrossingPolygon` also work.

Comment: It does not work in 13.0. You can make it work for PDF and PNG with: `Rasterize[Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Polygon[data]}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for undesirable filling and rasterization on `Export` is that the points are partially reversed, what results in a polygon with self-intersections. Fixing this:

```
g3 = Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Polygon[Join[data[[;; 251]], Reverse@data[[252 ;;]]]]}, 
   Frame -> True];
Export["sector.pdf", g3] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

The file is exported in vectors.

As to the edge added, it appears to be a bug. I observe it with versions 13.0.0 and 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64, but not with version 8.0.4 on the same machine. Reported to the support as [CASE:4897465].

Answer (score 1):

That's the edge you see if you plot `Line@data`.

[image]

Workaround:

```
reg = CanonicalizePolygon[Polygon@data]

g3 = Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, reg,
   }
  , Frame -> True
  ]

Export["C:/sector.pdf", g3]
```

Comment: It words well, but there is Bitmap Image in pdf file, not a Vector image. (just like png file)